# Google play upload updated APK Suspended

Tags: android, google-play

I am completely fresher to android application development.I am create a new application. And i publish the application thru play store..

- > First time i will upload and publish the app successfully thru play store..
  >   example(App Name : Application 1.0),
- > Further i am update my apk file and try to upload updated apk thru play store.
  >   example(App Name : Application 2.0)

**And i am getting error,**

> **See the below screen shots :**

[image: Screen One]
[image: Screen two]

> ***And after couple of minutes i am get the new email from
>    googleplay-developer-support...***

[image: Screen Three]

> I am didn't use any third parties icons/tittle etc.. And i am try to 
>   **policy support team.**
>
> My Question was

- How to upload the updated apk properly?
- How to fix this issue?

Please help me!!

Answer (score 1):

Click **"Contact our support team"** and provide your justification such as a document proving you have full access to contents used in app. If justification is apt, then your app(2.0) will be updated automatically/you will just have to change something in description, etc and click update in publisher account.

Comment: @Vijay kumar google contact will take up-to 72 hours. Please wait. If your justification is correct and you are not using any copyright content, then your app will be live or will be ready to be updated before 72 hours.

Comment: Thanks for your reply..Any proper document to upload the updated apk?

Comment: I had an app which had the same issue, I uploaded a document, that was  written on my clients letter head and which said that I have full rights to use the contents inside the app along with their seal. Sorry, but I cannot provide a sample for this.

Answer (score 0):

> Finally i get the mail from Google support team,,

My Exception was, I am just adding miss match **privacy policy** copy..

**That so i getting this error!!!**